# Location of labels

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to determine if a label is in a given location on a form. Basically the user will drag a panel into 1 of 225 labels and I need to determine which label the panel is on.

Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "sender" parameter that is given in most GUI events represents the control which generated the event.

Also, you can call the GetChildAtPoint() function to get the control present at a given mouse location.